# Android javac and dx - trouble processing, class name and path do not match

Tags: java, android, compilation, dalvik, dx

I'm using SpartacusRex's Terminal IDE and another app, DroidEdit, to build and run java applications on Android. A simle one-file Hello World builds and runs flawlessly, however when i introduce packages i cannot properly dex the class files into a jar file:

From my project directory:
javac src/mypack/*.java
**This Compiles Successully**
dx --dex --output=Test.jar src
**This gives my the following warning**

*trouble processing:

class name (mypack/Main) does not match path (Main.class)

... while parsing Main.class

... while processing Main.class*

All paths and package names are correct. Main.java is in a folder called "mypack" and has a packgage statement "package mypack;".
What am I doing wrong ?
Also, using --no-strict removes the warning but the outputted jar file is not built correctly and cannot be run.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

You must put the class files inside a directory named exactly like it's package name and then create the jar file from it.

for example **com.test.me.MyActivity** must be at **com/test/me/MyActivity.class**

Answer (score 0):

According to your question all *.class files are in `mypack/` directory so issue following command it might help you.

```
dx --dex --output=classes.dex src/mypack/
```

`dx` will pick all the files from `mypack` directly.
Consider reading this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15089370/unable-to-execute-java-file-through-davik-vm/15112252#15112252).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same development environment and the same problem.
the sollution is to use intermediate jars.

1. first compile the classes with packages. `javac -d classes
   $srclist`
2. create intermediate jars (only 1 arg allowed) `jar cf
   $idedir/a.jar a jar cf $idedir/b.jar b`
3. create executable dx jar
   `dx --dex --verbose --output=$jarfile $idedir/a.jar $idedir/b.jar`

then the dx jar has the correct package for each class