# Unable to execute .java file through Davik VM

Tags: java, dalvik

I am following this  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10199863/how-to-execute-the-dex-file-in-android-with-command)
I have first executed this command successfully.

```
javac <path + filename>.java
```

Then after when I am trying to execute following command I facing an error "**class name does not match path**".

`dx --dex --output=<path + filename>.dex <path + filename>.class`

I have same name for .class and .java but I think I have to write explicit path of .class file name. So what to do now. There is some minor mistake that I am doing but not able to find.

Comment: Have a look one more time on @JesusFreke post and check if you are following what he said

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid magic number problem ,First check your jdk version ,it seems there is a problem with jdk 1.7* . i reverted  to jdk 1.6 .

Instead of  using `dx --dex --output=<path + filename>.dex <path + filename>.class`
we can do one thing put one or all your .classes files in one folder say `classFolder` 
now issue following command :

```
dx --dex --output=YourClass.dex  absolutePath/classFolder
```

dx command will pick one or all class files in that folder .

Comment: I have checked ma version is 1.6.0.27. And I made one folder and put .class file into in and executed the command but I am facing the same error sir.

Comment: trouble processing : bad class file magic(cafebabe) or version (0033.0000) ...while parsing absolute path/helloworld.class 1 warning no classfiles specified.

Comment: Try editing proguard.bat file in  (Android SDK\tools\proguard\bin) , instead of "call %java_exe% -jar "%PROGUARD_HOME%"\lib\proguard.jar %*" change it to "call %java_exe% -jar "%PROGUARD_HOME%"\lib\proguard.jar %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9" .

Comment: My proguard.bat file is -> @ECHO OFF
REM Start-up script for ProGuard -- free class file shrinker, optimizer,REM obfuscator, and preverifier for Java bytecode.
REMREM Note: when passing file names containing spaces to this script,REM you'll have to add escaped quotes around them, e.g.
REM "\"C:/My Directory/My File.txt\""IF EXIST "%PROGUARD_HOME%" GOTO homeSET PROGUARD_HOME=..:home

java -jar "%PROGUARD_HOME%"\lib\proguard.jar %*

Comment: In the last line "java -jar "%PROGUARD_HOME%"\lib\proguard.jar %" .

Comment: trouble processing:
bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0033.0000)
...while parsing E:/Projects/Java/Android/HelloWorld/src/com/hello/world/HelloWo
rld.class
...while processing E:/Projects/Java/Android/HelloWorld/src/com/hello/world/Hell
oWorld.class
1 warning
no classfiles specified

Comment: this my proguard.bat @ECHO OFF

REM Start-up script for ProGuard -- free class file shrinker, optimizer,
REM obfuscator, and preverifier for Java bytecode.
REM
REM Note: when passing file names containing spaces to this script,
REM       you'll have to add escaped quotes around them, e.g.
REM       "\"C:/My Directory/My File.txt\""

IF EXIST "%PROGUARD_HOME%" GOTO home
SET PROGUARD_HOME=..
:home "call %java_exe% -jar "%PROGUARD_HOME%"\lib\proguard.jar %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25239/discussion-between-imposter-and-yash-raj-dave)

Answer (score 5):

dx is picky about the paths that you give it - the relative path of the class file relative to your working directory has to match the package of the class.

For example, if your command is

```
dx --dex --output=classes.dex out/com/example/HelloWorld.class
```

Then dx assumes that the package name of HelloWorld should be out.com.example, and complains if it isn't.

However, there is a trick - you can add a `/./` path component in the path you give dx, to specify where the "root" is, with respect to the java package. If the package in the previous example is actually com.example, then you can do:

```
dx --dex --output=classes.dex out/./com/example/HelloWorld.class
```

Another option is to use the --no-strict option, which disables dx's path checks.

Comment: Is it not necessary class.dex and helloworld.class both must have same name?

Comment: no, it is not necessary. A dex file is not tied to a single class - it typically contains many classes.

Comment: I have solved it by making .class file to .jar. Thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

Your command seems to be wrong:

```
dx --dex --output=.dex .class
```

Have you tried this?

```
dx --dex --output=YourClass.dex YourClass.class
```

Comment: Its showing as a warning. Class name dont match path (path + filename.class).

Comment: @YashRajDave call `javac` and `dex` in the same folder where your file is. Are you using any package, what is it name?

Comment: Package name is com.hello.java.

Comment: I called javac and dex in same folder as you suggested.  After executing dex command its showing "bad class file magic (cafebabe) or verison(0033.0000) while parsing <path + filename>.class".1 warning. no classfiles specified.

Comment: `<path + filename>` what is that? Why are keep using that notation, it makes more confusing.

Comment: dx --dex --output=E:\ProjectsJava\Android\HelloWorld\src\com\hello\world\HelloWorld.dex E:\ProjectsJava\Android\HelloWorld\src\com\hello\world\HelloWorld.class

Comment: I am facing the problem executing last command shown in that link. It is showing that "dalvik: permission denied", when I typed this command: adb shell ANDROID_DATA=/sdcard dalvikvm -cp /sdcard/HelloWorld.zip HelloWorld